# knockout click event is canceled by focusout event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

i have a form with input tag and "X" button to clean the input value. 
this button should be hidden when the input doesn't have a focus, so i have a focusout event to hide it when the input is out of focus. but when the user clicks on the "X" button - it goes first to the focusout event and the click event of this button is not called.

here is my html:

```
 <input type="text" id="entityName" data-bind="value: name" maxlength="100"     name="name" />
 <span class="clearTextIcon" data-bind="click:$root.clearText"></span>
```

here is my code

```
this.clearText = function (o, e){
                $(e.target).prev().val('');
            };

            $('body').on('focusout', 'input', function(e){
                    $(this).siblings('.clearTextIcon').hide();

            });
```

Comment: This is just a typo in question right?! `$(this);.siblings`

Comment: yes, thanks.it should be $(this).siblings('.capbClearTextIcon').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need this jQuery stuff at all. Just use the `visible` binding handler:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: name,
                              valueUpdate: 'input',
                              hasFocus: name.editing" />

<span data-bind="event: { mousedown: $root.clearText },
                 visible: name() && name.editing()">X</span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.clearText = function(){
        self.name('');
    };

    this.name = ko.observable('');
    this.name.editing = ko.observable(false);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

See [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUTKL/2).

Comment: thanks for your answer. this can help me to hide it when there is no value in the input, but how can i hide it when the user is not focus on the input?